# Delete Registry Key with spaces at the end of line through VBS

Tags: vbscript, registry, whitespace

It seems that `reg delete` does not work with keys that have spaces at the end. I'm trying to delete a key with spaces, for example:

```
"HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Sample "
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to delete this, I already use the replace and trim function to convert the registry without space, but unfortunately I can't get it to work.

```
RegDeleteKey "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\samplekey ", "TMPUSER"

Function SetKeys(SID)
    RegDeleteKey "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains\sampleykey ", SID
End Function

Sub RegDeleteKey(KeyPath, Mode)
    Dim CMD

    If Mode = "TMPUSER" Then
        KeyPath = "TMPUSER\" & KeyPath
    Else
        KeyPath = Mode & "\" & KeyPath
    End if

    CMD = "REG DELETE " & chr(34) & "HKEY_USERS\" & KeyPath & chr(34) & " /f"

    objshell.Run CMD, 0, True   
End Sub
```

Comment: Please show how do you try to delete the key (a piece of script)?

Comment: @duDE i already included some piece of the script that I used to delete a key, it actually delete a key that has no spaces at the end of line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to use `reg.exe` at all. The [WshShell object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aew9yb99(v=vs.84).aspx) has a [`RegDelete` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/293bt9hh%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). The docs say:

> Specify a key-name by ending `strName` with a final backslash; leave it off to specify a value-name.

So...

```
Dim Shell: Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")


If TryRegDelete("HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Sample \") Then
    WScript.Echo "Success!"
Else
    WScript.Echo "Could not delete key."
End If

Function TryRegDelete(strName)
    On Error Resume Next
    Shell.RegDelete(strName)

    TryRegDelete = Err.Number = 0
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```